# Decoding Byte/Bits to Binary

Tags: python, byte, decoding, bit, gpib

I am using a Prologix GPIB-USB adaptor in a LISTEN only mode to decipher communication between two equipments (Semiconductor related namely Tester and Prober).

I am able to decode most of the information as stated in the Manual , But unable to convert one of the Data namely BIN Category.

Sample Data :

```
018022
C@A@@@@@@@
Q
O
A
A
019022
CA@A@@@@@@
```

Tool Manual :

[image: Manual on How to read Incoming Data]

The data i am interetsed in are "C@A@@@@@@@" and "CA@A@@@@@@"
The First byte namely "C" is the command which is passed in.
The Second Byte which can be "@" or "A" actually tells if the Test is Pass/Fail.

converting to binary :

```
@ ---> 0100 0000
A ---> 0100 0001
```

The Result is decided by the lower 4 bits of the Byte which is 0000(Pass) and 0001 (Fail). I am able to decode it correctly until here .

The next 8 Bytes represent the BIN category , which during test was set as 5 if the test fail and 1 if it is Pass  , so BIN number in "C@A@@@@@@@" is 1 and BIN number corresponding to "CA@A@@@@@@" is set at 5.

I am unable to decode the value of 5 and 1 from the data which is generated from GPIB adaptor. Can someone suggest if it can actually be decoded as 5 and 1. I have attached the Manual which explain on how to read incoming Data.

Stuck with this for long time :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use struct.unpack to decode byte values to numbers. You need to know the length (in this case 8 bytes) and whether the number is big or little endian (test if you don't know).  And whether the number is signed or unsigned.

If your string is  "C@A@@@@@@@" and the binary data is in bytes 3-10, you could try

```
import struct    
foo="C@A@@@@@@@"
print struct.unpack(">Q", foo[3:11])
```

This would decode a 8 bytes long unsigned big-endian number. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html for instructions.

Hope this helps.

Hannu